# How to add headers for single request in chopper?

Tags: android, ios, networking, flutter

I am trying to add headers to specific request using Chopper in flutter.I know about interceptors and I have used them, but I have case where I want to add header to a specific request. Please help me how can I add header. I have tried out the following code, Moreover didn't found anything on this link of Chopper https://pub.dev/packages/chopper/versions/1.0.0

```html
@Get(path: "/mobile/top", headers: {"UID": "{uid}"})
Future<Response> getTopUsers(@Header() String uid);
```

I will be very thankful if you guide on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to pass your headers with chopper. All depends if the headers are part of constructor method or they are parameter headers.

```
// Headers (e.g. for Authentication) can be added in the HTTP method constructor
// or also as parameters of the Dart method itself.
@Get(path: "/mobile/top", 
     headers: {'Constant-Header-Name': 'Header-Value'}
// Parameter headers are suitable for ones which values need to change
Future<Response> getTopUsers([
     @Header('Changeable-Header-Name') String uid,
)];
```